# Mix Shader with 2 transparent PNGs - color changed when it should not

Tags: shaders, transparency

**The goal**

I want a material that will have two decals painted on the mesh.

**The process**

I do that by combining two transparent PNGs into one mask that is used to replace the primary paint with black color.

**The problem**

Notice on the two screenshots attached how the bottom portion of the object (around the "brand" sign) becomes very-very-slightly dimmer when the 2nd transparent PNG is introduced  via the Math(Add) shader.

(It does not seem to make any difference when I split the object into two meshes.)

[image: only one transparent PNG]

[image: two transparent PNGs combined]

**The file**

[image]

**What I tried**

Turning on Clamp on the Math(Add) shader, sadly no luck:

- on the left: two PNGs mixed, results in slightly dimmer color
- on the right: only one PNG involved, color is correct

[image]

Comment: Try enabling Clamp on that Add maths node. That will limit the Fac to range 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: @RichSedman gave it a shot, no luck... thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

The root cause was in one of the two UV-mappings...

...all the irrelevant faces somehow ended up collapsed into a singular vertex, which was sitting at a not-completely-transparent pixel at [0;0] coords, hence slightly affecting the paint color in the render output.